# How can I make a geo location query in CBL?

Tags: android, geolocation, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am using CBL for Android. I have the latitude and longitude values that the user saved earlier. And there are also values for the location the user has marked on the map.

I need to make a query on the database using the location information the user has selected on the map. So if the records in the database are located near the location the user chose, I want to show this.

How can I do that. I have no idea how to query this in CBL. I would be very glad if you could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box query support. From discussion thread posted [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/geospatial-queries-for-couchbase-lite-xamarin-forms-net-standard-app/18942/4),

> It’s possible to do bounding-box queries without specialized indexes;
> for example (pseudocode) loc.x BETWEEN $x0 AND $X1 AND loc.y BETWEEN
> $y0 AND $y1. With regular indexes on loc.x and loc.y (as opposed to
> R-trees) this isn’t very efficient, but it’s workable as long as your
> data set isn’t too large.